# what event (change, keyup, etc.) should I choose to filter data from an array using an input text using a optimal way

Tags: angular

I have a project in which I want to filter data in an array of more than a thousand positions, but for performance reasons I suppose that it is very ineffective to repeat actions key by key (when the user writes letter by letter). What is the most effective way to do it?

```
 <input (keyup)="fn_filterData()" ([ngModel])="filter">

 fn_filterData(){
 this.myArray.filter((item)=>{
  return item.search(filter)!=-1;
 })
}
```

I don't know if something is possible so that after 2 seconds in which you stop typing in the text field, the search is done, to make it more optimal or something like that.

I usually use a pipe, but this is activated when typed letter by letter. Which is the best way?

Comment: Angular documentation recommends _not_ using a pipe for filtering as it is likely to trigger filtering too frequently: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com)'s observables with [debounceTime()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html), [distinctUntilChanged()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html), and [switchMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) operators can be used to do this optimally.

This approach ensures that data isn't filtered on every key press (waits for given time and groups characters), ignores filtering again when same key is entered immediately, and has other advantages.

Refer this [Building a Real Time Search in Angular With RxJS](https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/) post where this is implemented in search.

Here is an outline of how it can be done.

**Template:**

```
<input [ngModel]="filterKey" (ngModelChange)="onFilterKeyChange($event)">
```

**Component:**

```
filterKey: string;
inputs$ = new Subject<any>();

onFilterKeyChange(key) {
  this.filterKey = key;
  this.inputs$.next({ 'filterKey': this.filterKey });
}

inputs$.pipe(
  debounceTime(750), // Waits until there is no new data for given time.
  distinctUntilChanged( // Only allows distinct data to pass through.
    (p, q) => p.filterKey === q.filterKey
  ),
  switchMap(input => {
    // Has cancelling effect, ignores previous input when new key is entered.

    let key = input.filterKey.trim();

    // Filter the data.
    let result = this.items.filter(item => 
      item.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase())
    );

    return of(result);
  })
  .subscribe((result) => {
    this.filteredData = result;
  });
```

When you have thousands of records, it is better to filter them at the backend. In such case, just replace filtering logic in `switchMap()` with an API call.

```
.switchMap((input) => {
    let key = input.filterKey.trim();        
    return dataService.getFilteredData(key);
})
```

Live demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filtering-using-rxjs

Comment: Thanks! can you share the complete code please? I am new in angular in I am getting some errors..

https://imgur.com/OxEdiYu

I want try your code to understand it

Comment: @yavg - Check out my edited answer. I added link to a demo which I just created. I also made some syntactical changes according to the latest version of RxJS (v6).

Comment: Sorry for the time I took to answer you. Thank you very much, this code really excites me! I have 3 questions. What is the function in this case of "switchMap", I do not understand what the "of" does and finally what "$"(inputs$.next) what means?

Comment: You're welcome @yavg. All those are related to observables in RxJS. Angular uses RxJS a lot, so you might want to learn it gradually.  You can click on the links in my answer to read more about them.

`switchMap()` cancels previous inner observable and subscribes to new observable. `of()` sends objects or values in a sequence. Observables are usually represented by `$` sign at the end. In `inputs$.next()`, `inputs$` is an observable, and by calling `next()` method we are sending a new value to subscribers of that observable.

Hope this clarified it a little bit.